# Event binding to ViewModel events in XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, events, binding

WPF newbie here. Suppose my ViewModel class has an event `SomethingHappened` defined as:

```
Public Event SomethingHappened(message As String)
```

and there is a local resource in my View define as:

```
<local:MsgWindow x:Key="MsgWindow" Visibility="Hidden" >
```

The ViewModel is assigned as the `DataContext` of the View. How do I change the `Visibility` of my MsgWindow to `Visible` upon `SomethingHappended`?

Answer (score 1):

I would define a bool property in your view model, create BoolToVisibilityConverter (implementing IValueConverter), and bind Visibility property in XAML to your model's property with the converter. Instead of raising the event, set your property (ensure your property raises PropertyChanged from INotifyPropertyChanged OR is a dependency property).

Comment: Yep, that's right, but I was more interested in finding the XAML way of event-binding than a workaround to the specific instance of the problem at hand.

Comment: ah; well you could try an event trigger

Answer (score 0):

In the resources, declare:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
```

Then in your view-model declare:

```
public bool Visible { get; set; }
```

And then, bind your component to this property with the converter

```
<local:MsgWindow x:Key="MsgWindow" Visibility="{Binding Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
```